# Ubuntu 22.04 problems with window controls

Tags: updates, graphics, windows

1.After updating ubuntu to 22.04, I have graphics issues with all windows controls...
 [problems with window controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m0H8.jpg)

Window controls and some texts do not appear until you hover the mouse over the element.

2.If I minify a jpg image on a TinyJPG page, and I want to download a minified image, then google chrome crashed without any error message.

Updating ubuntu wasn't a good idea :(

update:
I have the same problem in some notification windows e.g.:libreofice notification windows (print window)...
In Google Chrome => customize and controls => Downloads => crashed Chrome without error message (before acutalization was everything ok)

When the system is turned on, the following is displayed:

```
[ 0.128892] x86/cpu: SGXdisabled by BIOS.
[ 0.196359] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failurecreating namedobject [\_SB.PCI0.RP05.PXSX.TBDU], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
[ 0.196367] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
/dev/nvme2n1py: clean, 1162939/30490624 files,47145706/121938432 blocks
[ 4.009210] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: 12c_transferfailed -6
[ 4.009232] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -6
[ 4.253617]
```

Turn off:

```
[ 27.610738] psmouse serio1: Failedtodisable mouse on isa0060/serio1
[FAILED] Failed to  start Network Manager Wait Online.
```

Comment: What are your hardware specs and what does system information say?

Comment: GT75 Titan 8SG 

Hardware Model: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. GT75 Titan 8SG
Memory: 32GB
Processor: Intel® Core™ i9-8950HK CPU @ 2.90GHz × 12
Graphics: NVIDIA Corporation TU104BM [GeForce RTX 2080 Mobile]
+ 2 external monitors in 4k

OS Name: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
OS Type: 64-bit
GNOME Version: 42.0
Windowing System: X11

Comment: Did you already install the Nvidia drivers by running `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Comment: after `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and restart - without change, Another problem - file icons are not displayed on the desktop (text/file name only)

Comment: It's a long shot but try installing some themes and then switch to a different theme. Also, it might help to reinstall your current theme. If you were using a custom theme from your last version, it might not be compatible with 22.04. Lastly, try logging in as guest and see if the problem is still there. If not, you can safely bet that it's a configuration or user specific problem.

Comment: no change... i use default themes

Comment: When logged as guest, than looks like everything is ok, but in chrome when i want download samoe file than crashed with `chrome crashed with signal5`

Comment: second login as quest => same problems

Answer (score 2):

unbelievable, all my problems were caused by the setup Displays => Fractional Scaling, after disabled => everything OK

Comment: in my case it's disabled, but the same issue